# a example of two space that are homotopy equivalent but not homeomorphic

Tags: general-topology

Is $D^2$ and the point space $P$ containing a point of $D^2$ homeomorphic? Are the two space of same homotopy type?

> I am seeking for a example of two space that are homotopy equivalent but not homeomorphic.

Comment: A point and a line are homotopic (a line is contractible) but not homeomorphic, and they have different cardinalities.

Comment: what about $P$ and $D^2$?

Comment: No, they are not homeomorphic. Remember that a homeomorphism is also a bijection...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Any [contractible space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contractible_space) is by definition homotopy equivalent to the one-point space, for instance an interval, a disk, the real line, the Euclidean plane, $\mathbb{R}^n$, Bing's [house with two rooms](http://sketchesoftopology.wordpress.com/2010/03/25/bings-house/), etc. Any space with more than a single point is not homeomorphic to the one-point space because cardinality is a homeomorphism invariant.